# Are Rails ActiveRecord presence validations useful if other validations would fail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

If I have validations that require certain values in a field, like a `format: { with: some_regex }` or an `inclusion: { in: some_array }` that will fail on blank or nil, is setting the validation `presence: true` useful in any way? In the same situation, is the `length: { }` validation useful if the other validations would fail?

Similarly, could a length validation of {1..n} preclude the need for a presence validation?

I'm trying to learn if there is something more going on or if the checks are simply redundant. For instance, the Rails Tutorial has a `presence: true` validation on the email address but the format validation should not allow a blank or nil address. Seems redundant, or is it style/convention?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using something like `format: regex` and you can guarantee (easy enough through a unit test) that a blank or nil attribute will cause the whole record to be invalid, then yes you don't need to validate the presence. Same with the `inclusion` situation, and the `length` situation.

In general, adding *more* validations isn't necessarily a bad thing. But, if you've thoroughly tested your model for situations with blank or nil attributes and your current validations achieve the desired result, then you're fine.

Answer (score 0):

Validation of presence if **weaker** then anything mentioned. I'd rather not put

```
validates presence: true
```

having, for instance,

```
validates format: { with: some_regex }, allow_blank: false
```

as the later already would cover the situation with the field having `nil` value.